# NullPointerException when using setExitTransition to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, transition

I am trying to animate my fragment's enter and exit. `setEnterTransition` works fine, but if I use `setExitTransition`, it throws a nullPointerException. If I use `setReturnTransition`, it doesn't show any animation.

Here's what I have.

```
private void showFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = JoinGroupFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Log.i(TAG, "set enter transition");
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.TOP));
//      fragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM));
    }

    ft.commit();
}

private void dismissFragment() {
    Fragment joinGroupFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (joinGroupFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//      ft.hide(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.remove(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Now, If I use `setExitTransition`, I'm getting following error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int
>   android.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference
>               at android.app.BackStackRecord$1.onPreDraw(BackStackRecord.java:1131)
>               at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I looked around and found out that there's a bug raised regarding this. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82832

There's a workaround posted. I tried the same thing but with `FragmentManager` instead of supportFragmentManager, but I'm still facing the same issue.

The workaround that I tried

```
// This is in onCreate().
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment())
                    .addToBackStack("dummy")
                    .commit();
```

---

```
private void showFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = JoinGroupFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    // ft.addToBackStack("dummy");
    // ft.addToBackStack("my_backstack); // none of these work
    ft.commit();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Log.i(TAG, "set enter transition");
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.TOP));
        fragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM));
    }

    ft.commit();
}

private void dismissFragment() {
    Fragment joinGroupFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (joinGroupFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//      ft.hide(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.remove(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I know there aren't any fragments in the backstack for transition, but adding a dummy fragment also doesn't help. Is there any workaround for this?

### UPDATE

Instead of a dummy Fragment, I used the same fragment.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, JoinGroupFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack("dummy")
                        .commit();
```

---

```
private void showFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = JoinGroupFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.addToBackStack("dummy");
    ft.commit();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Log.i(TAG, "set enter transition");
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.TOP));
        fragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM));
    }

    ft.commit();
}

private void dismissFragment() {
    Fragment joinGroupFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (joinGroupFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//      ft.hide(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.remove(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

If I do this, when I call showFragment() for the first time, the previously added (in onCreate()) fragment shows exit transition and the new one shows enter transition, but when I call `dismissFragment()`, it still throws the same error. I have been keeping log of the backstack count using `getBackStackEntryCount()` and it shows 2 when removing the fragment and still the the error.

But I don't understand how the first fragment shows exit transition.

---

I also tried out this.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment())
                        .addToBackStack("dummy")
                        .commit();
```

---

```
private void showFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = JoinGroupFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.addToBackStack("dummy");
    ft.commit();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Log.i(TAG, "set enter transition");
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.TOP));
        fragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM));
    }

    ft.commit();
}

private void dismissFragment() {
    Fragment joinGroupFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (joinGroupFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment());
        ft.remove(joinGroupFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

This works well and shows exit transition. But `BackStackEntryCount` keeps on increasing despite of `remove` call which is increasing used memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I do not understand FragmentManager's backstack yet. What I was trying to do could be done without backstack. It is simple.

For Transition, I need to replace the fragment with some other fragment, otherwise it is not a transition.

```
private void showFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = JoinGroupFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    ft.commit();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.TOP));
        fragment.setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM));
    }

    ft.commit();
}

private void dismissFragment() {
    Fragment joinGroupFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JOIN_GROUP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (joinGroupFragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

This is working well. I'll try it with backstack also and post later.